MSI: when upgrading, delete a file that is implicitly the KeyPath of the component
I have an MSI (built with Wix 3) already distributed to customers. Among others, the product has a directory named Reporter that contains two files, A and B.
A is the implicit KeyPath, because it is the first entry in the XML.
For security reasons, we need to eliminate file A. So we need to produce an MSI that:

does not contain A
on upgrade, removes A, but keeps file B (in the same component, in the same directory)
on clean install, deploys only B (obviously)

Here is the current WXS file:
<Directory Id="DirX" Name="Reporter">
    <Component Id="componentX" Guid="47A2D991-AC4D-43C0-94F3-02E3D4D2AB3D" DiskId="1" Win64="yes">
        <File Id='A' Name='A' Source='A'/>
        <File Id='B' Name='B' Source='B'/>
    </Component>
</Directory>

<Feature Id="featureX" Title="bla" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="componentX" />
</Feature>

How can one reasonably accomplish this? Remarks:

no we cannot keep file A

it would be very nice to keep file B in the same directory (Reporter)

we usually perform minor upgrades

we don't really care about features or components, the product is usually installed as a whole by network admins, without user interference.


I tried everything I could find on the internet:

setting file B as KeyPath -> on upgrade, the entire directory Reporter is wiped.
creating a new feature, new component, new GUID, with only file B -> on upgrade, the entire directory Reporter is wiped.
using RemoveFile for file A -> same result

I am reluctant to create a custom action, but will do if that is the only way.

I would not expect the directory to get removed in all of those scenarios so verbose log files and a derailed analysis would be necessary. I'm not sure you'll find that is a good fit for StackOverflow.

Thank you Rob! I also don't know why, but I do see the feature and the component as absent in the log. In the end, I will just switch over to a new name for the directory, and eat the cost (mainly documentation).

In minor upgrades, removing a component or changing keypath won't work. You may refer below comparision:
https://docs.revenera.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm
Also, I believe if you delete a file using a custom action, Installer will try to bring it back due to its self healing feature on next minor upgrade/patch but yes your custom action will be executed every time to remove that.

Can't you just puncture this component and define a new one?
